# How to link two rows in attribute table to the same polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, relates

There are two rows in an attribute table. I want to link both rows to the same polygon. How can I do this?

Comment: You question is not very clear. If they are in the same attribute table they are already related, no?

Comment: I have a similar confusion.  It is not clear whether this is a feature attribute table or a standalone table.

Answer (score 2):

A feature only ever has one row in an attribute table.

If you have a requirement that suggests you need two or more then I recommend using a second table and adding a relate to it.

The help page [About joining and relating tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) is well worth reviewing.